# Duda Palindromo Java

Tags: java

estoy mirando ejemplos luego de hacer el examen de Java a papel que tuvimos hoy en clase, no es excusa, grandes mentes de la programación han sabido defenderse en el examen seguro. Pero bueno, a mi me cuesta el no poder comprobar, el debug, etc (el debug lo realizo yo mismo en una hoja aparta paso a paso) pero bueno. No estamos aqui para debatir la enseñanza.

Estaba revisando un ejercicio que consistia, simplemente, en decir si una cadena de texto es palindroma o no y yo he realizado esto:

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Ejercicio3 {
        public static void main (String[]args) {
        
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Introduce una palabra: ");
        
        String cadena_texto = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase(); /* Para que no distinguir entre minusculas y mayusculas */
        
        
        /* He pensando en lo siguiente, en mi cabeza, en ese momento, pensé , bueno, un bucle que empiece desde el inicio
           hasta el final y otro desde el final desde el principio, y sonaba genial. Pero a la hora de comprobarlo me dice 
           que llegado el momento, el bucle se encuentra fuera de rango y no se pueden comparar.
           
           Esto es, supongo, porque el primer bucle si escribo "Ana", la posición i equivale a (i=1,i=2,i=3).
           
           Mientras que, la posición j del siguiente bucle equivaldria a (j=3, j=2 , j=1) | j=3 al inicio porque como es la longuitud
           de la palabra y esta tiene tres letras pues eso. 
           
           Por lo que el rango , dentro del bucle i es hasta 3 y el bucle j hasta el 1. O asi lo entiendo yo vamos.*/
        
        
        for (int i=0 ; i<cadena_texto.length() ; i++ ) {
            
            for (int j = cadena_texto.length() ; j>0 ; j--) {
                
                if (cadena_texto.charAt(i) == cadena_texto.charAt(j)) {
                    
                    System.out.println("La palabra es palindroma");
                    
                }
                
                else { System.out.println("La palabra no es palindroma");
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Me gustaria que me comentarais 3 puntos:

1. ¿Lo que comento en el comentario extenso es cierto? Tal vez lo entienda asi pero no sea correcto. Quiero que me corrijais y poder hacer feedback a mi mismo.
2. ¿Como mejorais la lógica? Supongo que, practicando, si. Pero me gustaria saber igualmente.
3. ¿Este código se puede modificar de alguna forma "minima" y que funcione? Estoy viendo ahora otros ejemplos que andan en la red que me apuntare, pero por curiosidad, me gustaria saberlo.

Muchas gracias, perdonad la molestia.

Comment: Procura que tu pregunta sea _específica_, y que sea una sola. Si tu código es funcional, y quieres que se revise tu código como para buscar mejoras, debes preguntar en [codereview.se] (en inglés).

Comment: Está bien, disculpa!

Comment: Si hay errores al probar tu código, por favor ve a [edit] y añádelos, completos, junto con los datos que estás usando para probar :) Lo otro, estás diciendo que es palíndroma por cada posición hasta que deja de serlo? Valdría usar una variable booleana que se mantenga en un estado hasta que pruebes lo contrario y la cambies, con eso eliges el mensaje a mostrar. Otra cosa: en el caso que fuese palíndroma, si `j` va hasta 1, nunca revisas el índice `0`. Lo último: qué debería pasar si son de longitudes diferentes? Tenlo en cuenta al validar :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cadena_texto.length()` te devuelve el total de dígitos de la palabra.
Debes tener presente que en un `array` o en el uso de `chartAt()` el indice parte de 0,es decir si declaras un array de `4` valores sus indices sera `0,1,2,3`

```
cadena_texto.length()="paloma" //cadena_texto.length()=6
```

siguiendo lo anterior el indice 6 no existe osea `cadena_texto.lenght()` sera un indice que te arrojara el error fuera de rango y es por eso que el error que te salio se debe a esta linea de código

```
//debio ser cadena_texto.lenght()-1 y j>=0
    for (int j = cadena_texto.length() ; j>0 ; j--)
```

puede que le encuentres sentido a tu lógica de comparar el primer indice de la palabra con el ultimo indice y así sucesivamente sim embargo,siguiendo esa lógica estas dos palabras seran validadas como palidromo por que en la ultima iteración el primer indice sera igual al ultimo indice a=a

```
amara amapa
```

Existen diversas formas de resolver este ejercicio a partir del concepto de `palindromo`

> Palabra o expresión que es igual si se lee de izquierda a derecha que de derecha a izquierda.

aplicado en tu código podrías obtener la palabra original e invertirla con el for decreciente explicado y luego de ello simplemente compararlo usando `equals()`

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce una palabra: ");
    String cadena_texto = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    
    
     String reverso = "";
        
        for (int i = cadena_texto.length() - 1; i >=0; --i) {
//concatemas desde el ultimo indice hasta el primero para obtener la palabra invertida
              reverso = reverso + cadena_texto.charAt(i);
          }
    
        if (cadena_texto.equals(reverso)) {
          System.out.println(cadena_texto + " es palindromo");
        }
        else {
          System.out.println(cadena_texto + " no es palindromo");
        }
```

Comment: Mil gracias!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Siempre que piensas en bucles `for` piensas en declarar una variable `int i = 0;`... pero en realidad, los bucles son bastante más interesantes de lo que se suele pensar, permitiendo declarar múltiples variables, condición de salida y pasos de las variables!

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo con un único bucle for utilizando dos variables para recorrer la palabra a la vez:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Palabra a comprobar, hardcodeada para evitar toda la parte del user input
    final String word = "racecar";

    // Todas las palabras son palíndromos hasta que se demuestre lo contrario!
    boolean isPalindrome = true;

    /*
    * Declaro dos variables, i a 0 y j a la longitud -1 (para evitar el overflow), y dado
    * que recorremos el bucle desde las dos puntas, no necesito seguir recorriéndolo si la
    * i ya es mayor que la j puesto que eso significará que estoy comprobando cosas que ya 
    * había comprobado antes! Es lo mismo charAt(0) != charAt(4) que charAt(4) != charAt(0)!
    */
    for(int i = 0, j = word.length() - 1; i <= j; i++, j--){
        if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(j)) {
            // Si las letras no coinciden no es palíndromo, flag a false y salimos del bucle
            // No tiene sentido seguir iterando si ya sabemos que no es palíndromo
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // Utilizo un ternario para pintar la palabra "es" o "no es" en función de si es palíndromo o no
    // Podrías usar un if/else normal, pero así me ahorro escribir dos veces el mismo string :)
    System.out.println("La palabra " + word + (isPalindrome ? " es": " no es") + " un palíndromo");
}
```